# Why does read method from File class raise Errno::EPERM while trying to read /dev/mem as the root user with proper permissions?

Tags: ruby

I logged in as root user just to play around with `/dev/mem` with Ruby 2.6.0 on Arch Linux.

It works when I write:

```
File.open('/dev/mem', 'r') { |x| puts x.readpartial(50) }
```

Or:

```
File.open('/dev/mem', File::RDONLY) { |x| puts x.readpartial(50) }
```

But it raises `Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted @ io_fread - /dev/mem)`
when I try:

```
File.read('/dev/mem')
```

Or:

```
File.open('/dev/mem', File::RDONLY) { |x| puts x.read }
```

Why can't the read method from File class can't read /dev/mem while readpartial can?

Comment: My guess is that by trying to read the entire memory, you are violating some kernel checks when you get to the RAM.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html and https://superuser.com/questions/562249/attempting-to-access-ram-dev-mem-says-operation-not-permitted

Comment: As the superuser.com's post goes, but I have no 1 MB read restriction on Arch Linux. I can cat out the whole content.

Comment: Oh well, ok, I was wrong:
x.readpartial(1_048_576) works fine. But 1 more than 1,048,576 doesn't work. That means it can't read a single byte more than an MiB.

Comment: Ok.  That makes sense, then.  Thanks for following up with that.